# Python eve not responding after running for a couple of days

Tags: python, eve

I've set up a very simple python eve on a linux machine. Somehow, it always stops responding after running for a while. I don't have much experience on python programming and eve doesn't seem to have very nice log file.

Can someone please help me to look into the root cause?

Thanks,
Chunan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eve is a Flask application, so make sure that you are following [Flask Deployment instructions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/) when/if you're using it for prolonged period of times, and/or in production. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Nicola. Now it's running with Gevent. Let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

You are running something like this:

*>python yourPeve.py*

You need to run:

*>python yourPeve.py &*

The **&** simbol, will put the process in the background, so, when you close the terminal, the process won't be killed.

Comment: I tried nohup but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. Thanks anyway, Francisco.

Comment: You said that " it's running with Gevent", did you solve it ?

Comment: I guess so. Please follow Flask deployment instruction as Nicola suggested.